# Considering charge rotation as current

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, charge

Let us suppose I have a rod (non conducting) with a charge $q$ at its end, rotating with angular velocity $\omega$ from another end where $q$ is attached and length $R$. And need to get $\vec{B}$ at some point on its axis, distant $x$ from center of circle.

I present my two approaches here:

> $\vec{B}$ due to point charge $q$ moving with $\vec{v}$ at $\vec{r}$ from it is given by:$$\dfrac{\mu_{o}}{4\pi}\cdot q\cdot\dfrac{\vec{v}\times \vec{r}}{r^3}$$ $$\implies \vec{B}=\dfrac{\mu_{o}}{4\pi}\cdot q\cdot\dfrac{\omega\cdot R}{r^2}\ \ \ \text{as}\  \vec{v}\perp\vec{r}$$ here $r^2=R^2+x^2$.

Also,

> Now charge $q$ moving with $\omega$ can be treated as current $(I) $ 
>   in a loop of radius $R$ $$\implies I=q\cdot\dfrac{\omega}{2\pi}\tag{1}$$$\vec{B}$ at distance $x$ from it is, $$\dfrac{\mu_{o}\cdot I\cdot R^2}{2(R^2+x^2)^{3/2}}$$$$\implies \dfrac{\mu_{o}\cdot q\cdot\omega\cdot R^2}{2\cdot 2\pi(R^2+x^2)^{3/2}}\tag{from 1}$$$$\implies\vec{B}=\dfrac{\mu_{o}}{4\pi}\cdot q\cdot\dfrac{\omega\cdot R^2}{r^3}$$

These two $\vec{B}$ are not identical, please help me, do I calculated it wrong or I can't consider revolution of charge in circle equivalent to current $I$ ?

Comment: In the first example the magnetic field has components along and perpendicular to the axis whereas in the second example the perpendicular components cancel out. BTW Biot-Savart should not be used for a moving (accelerating in this case) single charge.